# How to copy files of same name from multiple sources?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, wildcard, xcopy

I have a file named `CM6` in various sources and subsources like

- `2016/05/17/CM6`
- `2015/05/17/CM6`
- `2016/05/CM6`

How can I copy all `*CM6` files into one destination directory using a wildcard?

I have tried:

```
XCOPY *\*\*\*CM6 destination_folder
```

Comment: `XCOPY *\*\*\*CM6 destination_folder` it is not working.

Comment: You can't have more than 1 file with the same name in the same directory, so you would have to rename them upon copy.

Comment: I edited your question to add the `XCOPY` attempt, but you should still edit the question to explain what you mean by "it is not working." What exact errors or output does that give you? Also, you should edit to clarify your desired outcome because as @kizeloo points out, you can't have two files in the same folder with the same name.

Comment: You can't have wildcards `*` as path of a file path only as part of the file name or extension.